# ASP.NET 5 returns 502.3 – Bad Gateway

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

**Given:** 
A new empty ASP.NET 5 beta8 project. I added some controller and basic views which are working.

A Controller like this:

```
public class AccountController : Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(vm.UserName, vm.Password, vm.RememberMe, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

When I try to call the this services  I get the error page with a BadRequest 
I 've a breakpoing at the first line of code (`ModelState.IsValid`) which is not called.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, for "Bad Request" error, you'll have to show your request. Also, the title of the question says "Bad Gateway"...

Comment: 502.3 is given when the request is timed out. Check the WebConfig. Try to build the solution once again and let me know.

Comment: @haim770 its a 502.3 not a 503. The Request is a simple json object, also the request class has only optional fields. I can post details this afternoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason and it was not obivious what it was i post it as answer to my own questions as I think this could save someone a lot of time.

**In-Short:**

As a summary i would say, that invalid Exceptions in Services which are added to the serviceCollection could lead to this error when they are for first time injected.

**Details**

I Added a custom UserStore to the ServiceCollection

```
   services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyUserRole>(config =>
            {
                config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
                .AddUserStore<MongoUserStore>()
                .AddRoleStore<MongoUserStore>();
```

The Problem was that **MongoUserStore** Implemented a wrong interface. It implemented `IRoleStore<MyUser>` instead of `IRoleStore<MyUserRole>`. And as the controller recevied a instanz of the `SignInManager` there were invalidoperation exceptions which did not bubble up.
As I fixed this, the service is working